# How to use Action (Of IDataReader) in VB.NET (.NET Framework 3.5)

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

i have some code in C# that need to translate to vb.net (.NET Framework 3.5)

```
_dbObj.GetRowData("select * from mytable where myfield = @myfield", param, (IDataReader reader) =>
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            foo.p1 = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("field1"));
            foo.p2 = (int)reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("field2"));
            foo.p3 = (int)reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("field3"));
        }
    });
```

The GetRowData method:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
{
    conn.Open();

    if (param != null)
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);

    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
    {
        processor(reader);
    }
}
```

The "problem" is to translate the code to VB.NET. I think this snippet its ok:

```
Using conn As New SqlConnection(connstr)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(commandText, conn)
        conn.Open()
        If param IsNot Nothing Then
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param)
        End If

        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            processor(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

but when i need to use it i get an compiler syntax error

```
    _dbObj.GetRowData("select * from mytable where myfield = @myfield", param, Function (reader As IDataReader ???????)
While ??
```

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Sub instead of a Function:

```
_dbObj.GetRowData("select * from mytable where myfield = @myfield", param, 
      Sub(reader As IDataReader) 
          While reader.Read()
              foo.p1 = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("field1"))
              foo.p2 = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("field2"))
              foo.p3 = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("field3"))
          End While
      End Sub)
```

Comment: P.S - there is no need to do a cast of an int to an int: (int)reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("field1")).... you are already getting an int via the "GetInt32" method. :) - I know you didn't write the code but just commenting on the original.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Thanks, that cast sytnax wouldn't have compiled in VB anyway (fixed now).

Comment: @Joel thanks for the edit -- I also didn't realize you'd already answered.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn hmmm....i'm using .NET Framework 3.5 and i think Sub isn't supported. I only can use AddressOf or Function

Comment: Are you using VS2010 or higher?  It should be there http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: VS2008 only allowed inline lambda functions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253%28v=vs.90%29.aspx. You can put the expression into a separate sub and use AddressOf, but you'll lose the context for the foo object, so you'll have to workaround that.

Answer (score 1):

Your GetRowData snippet looks ok to me. I assume `processor` is the name of the `Action(Of IDataReader)` parameter.

The return value of `Action<T>` is `void`, so you need to declare your lambda function as a `Sub`, not a `Function`.

```
_dbObj.GetRowData("select * from mytable where myfield = @myfield", param, Sub(reader As IDataReader)
        While (reader.Read())
            foo.p1 = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("field1"))
            foo.p2 = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("field2"))
            foo.p3 = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("field3"))
        End While
    End Sub)
```